# why i can add id to android studio 3.0 Although i add id to activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Developing and I Download android studio 3.0  because my computer has amd processor. I found a lot of problem which one of them I can't use the android virtual device but these not problem .

I cant add id to main activity although I'm add the id in  `activity_main.xml`

**Images of problem**

1. https://www.mediafire.com/view/a0pz08jc5ac95qa/das.PNG
2. https://www.mediafire.com/file/8cacjf5xxs2azvv/sad.PNG

Comment: Read the docs or do some basic tutorials before you use stackoverflow. The solution is to use `Button button = findViewById(R.id.button)`

Comment: i'm use android studio 3.0 canary it's use kotlin language i try add your line but note work

Comment: Check our some tutorials. AS 3 supports Kotlin but it uses Java by default

Comment: thanks i now the problem the android studio don't convert java code to android code so i go to code and chose convert java code to kotlin code and start add the id ^_^